# Bad Request: XML cannot be parsed 400 error Curl PHP

Tags: php, xml, curl, xml-parsing, bad-request

I am using PHP POST Curl request to pass XLM data but I am getting an error in response:

> Bad Request: XML cannot be parsed. Check the XML you are sending to
> make sure it can be parsed.

```
$url = 'https://provapi.advancedmd.com/processrequest/API-100/DOKTORCONNECT/xmlrpc/processrequest.aspx';

$xmldata = '<ppmdmsg action="addpatient" class="demographics" msgtime="3/20/2018 2:52:07 PM"><patientlist><patient respparty="SELF" name="smith,BOB" sex="M" genderidentity="" genderidentityother="" orientation="" orientationother="" hipaarelationship="18" relationship="1" dob="03/11/1952"ssn="444-44-4444" additionalmrn="" chart="AUTO" profile="prof18" finclass="fclass16" language="44" inactivestatus="" title="MR" maritalstatus="1" employer=""><address zip="15136" city="MC KEES ROCKS" state="PA" address1="" address2="123 Main Street"/><contactinfo homephone="" officephone="" officeext="" otherphone="" othertype="" preferredcommunicationfid="" confidentialcommunicationfid="" communicationnote="" email="" emailverificationstatus="0"/></patient></patientlist><resppartylist><respparty name="SELF" accttype="4"/></resppartylist></ppmdmsg>';

$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: text/xml';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST,"POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xmldata);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headers);
//Send the request
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 300);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$array_data = json_decode(json_encode(simplexml_load_string($response)), true);
print_r('<pre>');
print_r($array_data);
print_r('</pre>');
```

The response is as following:

```
Array
(
    [Results] => Array
        (
        )

    [Error] => Array
        (
            [Fault] => Array
                (
                    [faultcode] => Client
                    [faultstring] => Client Error
                    [detail] => Array
                        (
                            [code] => 400
                            [description] => Bad Request: XML cannot be parsed
                            [extrainfo] => Bad Request: XML cannot be parsed. Check the XML you are sending to make sure it can be parsed.
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the API you are calling is bugous! Try assigning your variable like this:

```
$xmldata = <<<XML
<ppmdmsg action="addpatient" class="demographics" msgtime="3/20/2018 2:52:07 PM">
    <patientlist>
        <patient respparty="SELF" name="smith,BOB" sex="M" genderidentity="" genderidentityother="" orientation=""
                 orientationother="" hipaarelationship="18" relationship="1" dob="03/11/1952" ssn="444-44-4444"
                 additionalmrn="" chart="AUTO" profile="prof18" finclass="fclass16" language="44" inactivestatus=""
                 title="MR" maritalstatus="1" employer="">
            <address zip="15136" city="MC KEES ROCKS" state="PA" address1="" address2="123 Main Street"/>
            <contactinfo homephone="" officephone="" officeext="" otherphone="" othertype=""
                         preferredcommunicationfid="" confidentialcommunicationfid="" communicationnote="" email=""
                         emailverificationstatus="0"/>
        </patient>
    </patientlist>
    <resppartylist>
        <respparty name="SELF" accttype="4"/>
    </resppartylist>
</ppmdmsg>
XML;
```